# Stop setup error inside Custom Action With WIX installer

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3, wix3.6

Can i able to stop the setup if any error display inside CustomAction. As i can able display error message inside custom Action and it's dispaly the error message but as soon as i click on ok button my next UI sequence form is appearing.How i will force user to finish button?

Adding my source code:

```
<Binary Id="BIN_CustomAction" SourceFile="CustomAction.CA.dll" />
        <CustomAction Id="CA_CheckList" BinaryKey="BIN_CustomAction" DllEntry="CA_CheckList" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />

       <UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
            <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
            <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
            <DialogRef Id="UserRegistrationDlg" />
            <Dialog Id="UserRegistrationDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] Setup" NoMinimize="yes">

                <Control Id="ComboBoxMain" Type="ComboBox" X="124" Y="158" Width="241" Height="16" Property="LOCATIONNAME">
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="&amp;Back">
                    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>


                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="&amp;Next">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="SetupTypeDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>

            </Dialog>

            <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="&amp;NExt">
              <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="RadioButtonCheck">1</Publish>
            </Control>
          </Dialog>-->
            <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="UserRegistrationDlg" Order="3">
        LicenseAccepted = "1" 
      </Publish>
            <Publish Dialog="SetupTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="UserRegistrationDlg">1</Publish>
        </UI>
        <InstallUISequence>
            <Custom Action="CA_CheckList" Before="AppSearch">Not Installed</Custom>
        </InstallUISequence>

         [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CA_CheckList(Session session)
        {


            if (installer.ListStatus == false) 
            {

                // dispaly
                Record record = new Record();
                record.FormatString = string.Format("Error!");

                session.Message(
                   InstallMessage.Error | (InstallMessage)(MessageIcon.Error) |
                   (InstallMessage)MessageButtons.OK,record);

                return  ActionResult.Failure;   

            }
            else
            {
              return  ActionResult.Success;
            }



        }
```

Add screen shot also proving once i click on Ok button of image(1) my next dialog i.e image (2) is appearing:- instead of what i need is Finish dialog when i am getting the error.

1)[image: Error Message appears]

2) [image: Next Dialog]

```
Any idea??kindly help me.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post but I'd like to answer the question in case somebody else finds this.  In the custom action definition, CustomAction Id="CA_CheckList" BinaryKey="BIN_CustomAction" ..., 'Return' is set to 'ignore'.  It should be set to 'check'.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about returning the correct "error code" from the custom action. If you want to terminate the installation, return `ActionResult.Failure` from your CA.

Side note: displaying UI from inside the custom action is generally a bad idea - this scenario doesn't support silent installation the way it should go.

Comment: when i tried with ActionResult.Failure it still display's next button instead of Finish button.What could be the possible fix for this?

Comment: Is there any thing i need to do inside Install UI sequence if ActionResult is Failure currently this is what i am doing inside   <InstallUISequence>
 <Custom Action="CA_CheckList" Before="AppSearch">Not Installed</Custom>

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you return `ActionResult.Failure` from the custom action, it usually rolls back the installation. Depending on what UI you're using, it will or will NOT display the final "setup failed" dialog. AFAIK, the full UI scheme contains all dialogs required for your scenario.

Comment: If you don't mind can i provide what i am trying to do, can you help me if UI i am using is wrong as i am new to WIX setup.

Comment: @reapen, if you share the installation project source somehow, I can take a look (either later today or tomorrow)

Comment: i edited the actual question and provide the source code.thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: do you have time to go through the source code i provide above and can you help me how to solve the above issue?

Comment: yep, sorry for delay. It seems to me you've messed the things up with the UI part. Try just referencing the standard WiXUI_Mondo set, and see how your CA behaves. Also, try throwing an exception from your CA instead of returning `ActionResult.Failure` (this should lead to the same result, but try it anyway). Share what you get then

Comment: Hai Yan today only i could able to try with what you have mentioned above.Instead of ActionReult.Failure i tried with throwing exception from Custom Action but still as not getting the error dialog, as you said the same result only getting.I though to share with you.Anyway currently i changed the way of displaying the error message. If you come across this solved issue kindly share so that it can be helpful to others too.I really want to thank you Yan for your valuable time to look into my code and shared your viewpoints.